# Laravel view slash notation is not working

Tags: laravel, manjaro, php-7.3

I was developing a laravel application on windows and some of my team members decided to use slash notation for their views for example `return view('academics\index');`, I thought it would throw an error but it worked so I never bothered them to change it.

Now I move the same application over to manjaro linux and try to access that page and get:

> View [academics\index] not found

And when I change it to `return view('academics.index');` it works. Since those team members are no longer working on the project I can't ask them to change it, and I wouldn't want to go through the entire project to change it.

What's the simplest way to fix this issue?

**EDIT**: I should note that I was using php 7.2 on my windows and now I'm using php 7.3 on linux, I'm not sure if that would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel lets you use dot or slash notation, but only forward slash not backslash.

Are you sure the code shouldn't read `return view('academics/index');`?

Comment: Windows uses backslash \ as the directory separator. Unix based systems like Linux or Mac OS use /.

Comment: Oh ok, so is there a simple way to solve this issue because now I would have to go through the entire project to change them. Which is tedious because I might miss some

Comment: Not really. But what operating system do you plan on hosting this project on? If you are deploying it to a linux server you will have this issue anyway and it will need to be resolved. If you are hosting it on windows then you can either develop on windows, or follow the docs and either use the dot notation or forward slash.

Comment: It's already hosted on smarterasp and I'm gonna assume it's a windows OS because it works there as well

Comment: Then you can either develop on windows, but it would be better practice to change it to either forward slash or dot notation. That way in future if you did want to change to deploy on Linux it won't cause an issue.